# Some issues about installing gcc version 4.8.2 in redhat

Tags: gcc, redhat

n order to install caffe,which is used for deep learing,i need to upgrade gcc version from 4.4.7 to 4.8.2 in redhat 6.5。

```
First run ./configure it worked,
then make -j4, it will report 
options.c:11145: error: narrowing conversion of '-0x00000000000000001' from 'int' to 'short unsigned int' inside { }
g++ -std=gnu++0x -c   -g -DIN_GCC   -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I../../gcc -I../../gcc/. -I../../gcc/../include -I../../gcc/../libcpp/include  -I../../gcc/../libdecnumber -I../../gcc/../libdecnumber/bid -I../libdecnumber -I../../gcc/../libbacktrace    ../../gcc/hash-table.c -o hash-table.o
g++ -std=gnu++0x -c   -g -DIN_GCC   -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings -fno-common  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I../../gcc -I../../gcc/. -I../../gcc/../include -I../../gcc/../libcpp/include  -I../../gcc/../libdecnumber -I../../gcc/../libdecnumber/bid -I../libdecnumber -I../../gcc/../libbacktrace    ../../gcc/file-find.c -o file-find.o
make[3]: *** [options.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I search google,but can't find good ways to fix it ,who has the same issues before?

Comment: What version of gcc are you using to build gcc version 4.8.2 and what version of Red Hat are you using?

Comment: gcc version is 4.4.7-4

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the original gcc can cause problems.  The alternative is to install Developer Toolset which installs a new gcc version (currently at 4.9) along side the original to avoid file conflict.  Get started here:  http://developers.redhat.com/products/developertoolset/overview/