# An error when upgrading gcc on redhat6.6

Tags: gcc, redhat

I want to upgrade gcc on redhat from 4.7.7 to 4.8.2. When I run 'make', some error occured:

`options.c:11145: error: narrowing conversion of '-0x00000000000000001' from 'int' to 'short unsigned int' inside { }`

I found the same question([Some issues about installing gcc version 4.8.2 in redhat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353094/some-issues-about-installing-gcc-version-4-8-2-in-redhat)), but still feel confused about the solution.

---

PS:
Someone told me that installing gcc 4.8 on redhat6 is troublesome, and recommended me to upgrade the system to redhat 7.2 to avoid the upgrad. Because I was working on a new machine, so I adopted this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Agree to go to RHEL 7, as upgrading the base version of gcc is gnarly.

If you need to updated gcc versions in the future, look at the Developer Toolset which is part of the RHEL subscription and installs new gcc versions "along side" the original so won't mess up the OS: https://developers.redhat.com/products/developertoolset/updates/